# iPod Touch 4gen internet connection issues

Tags: ipod-touch, network, web-browser

Today I have a problem on my iPod Touch where there is a problem with internet connection using browsers (e.g. Google Chrome and Mobile Safari) but I also use Skype and it is working normally with no issues .

[image]

I assume that it is not a problem with WiFi connection because Skype works on my device and I can send messages and receive messages and I don't understand why the browsers are not working.

Comment: Is it jailbroken?

Answer (score 1):

I have made this solution:

- Open Settings
- Open General
- Open Reset
- Reset Network Settings

This process helped me.